# Passing builder atribute to a isolate widget on dart

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-futurebuilder

I am trying to pass a index attribute from an api to a image widget which show the network image, i get the undefined identifier error

[image: app.dart]

Answer (score 0):

I think you have missed to pass the index from MoviesList() widget to MovieCard Widget

Comment: how to pass it? i cant find anywhere in pub.dev

Comment: Make the MovieCard Widget like this.

`class MOvieCard extends StatelessWidget{
const MovieCard({
Key? key,
required this.movies,
required this.index,
}) : super(key: key);
final List<Movie>> movies;
final int index;
.
.
.
`
Then pass the index from itemBuilder while calling this widget